# "Treated" wood vs "Pressure Treated"

Tags: wood, pressure-treated

I recently bought what I thought was pressure treated railing pickets. But now that I look more carefully at the label, there is no [UC code](http://www.awpa.com/references/official.asp). My understanding is that each piece of PT has to be labeled with a UC code. This looks like PT, but the tag just says WeatherShield, and on the back of the tag: "Do not burn treated wood", and "Above Ground Use Only".

Does anyone have experience with this, or can tell me what it really is?

Answer (score 2):

No UC code could mean two things: either it was ripped off on purpose, or by accident, or its UC code is so low it doesn't rate to be classified (garbage). UC codes are "usage categories", running from UC1 (the lowest) to UC5 (the highest).

But the UC code is only half of it. A UC code must be matched to the retention rating of the chemical injected into the wood. This retention rating is called PCF (PCF = pounds per cubic foot), and shows how much more a cubic foot of wood will weigh after it's treated,:  For example a .25 PCF equates to weighing 1/4 lb heavier per cubic foot.

"Indoor" usage may be in the range of .15 to .20 PCF, which would place it in
and around UC1/UC2. I like to see a PCF number in and around .30 or .40 for outdoor exposure. .60 to .80 PCF is ground contact, and may be classified as Marine Duty   (certainly the good stuff)

Very low PCF ratings could be overcome by letting the wood dry out fully and giving it a soak coating of 2/3 varnish mixed with 1/3 mineral spirits (about a 30 to 40% reduction)
The reduction keeps it wet longer to get "soak in". I've gotten good long term results doing this.

I've seen very low PCF numbers (e.g. .02 / .03) which in my opinion is not worth
considering to purchase (garbage).

Answer (score 1):

It's pressure-treated just under a different process that is "greener". [See the PDF here](http://www.homedepot.com/hdus/en_US/DTCCOM/HomePage/Superfeatures/WeatherShield/Docs/Micro_treated_info.pdf). If it's treated, then there are preservatives in the wood to prevent rot and as an insect-repellant.

Comment: Hmm, how did you find this link? It is on the HD site, which is where I bought. "Osmose MicroPro" is similar sounding but different than my labeling "PROWOOD MICRO CA". The trouble with these kinds of descriptions is that they seem cover multiple product choices, and how can I know what I really have...

Comment: @Chris: It is on the Home Depot link provided by Mike Powell.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with it, but here's [Home Depot's WeatherShield page](http://www.homedepot.com/WeatherShield/h_d1/NCC-1701/h_d2/ContentView?pn=WeatherShield&storeId=10051&langId=-1&catalogId=10053).  That page mentions a limited lifetime warranty, which (assuming you purchased these at HD) you could probably get a copy of at the store if you're concerned.

Comment: Unfortunately the installation effort far out-strips the product's sticker price, and so no warranty is as important as knowledge and track record. - I'm replacing the builder's wood after 10 years, and I painted that 3 times.